# Convert Tensorflow.js into Tensorflow keras

Tags: keras, import, tensorflow.js

I have a tensorflow.js model and want to transform it into a TensorFlow Keras model. Is that in general possible? I have seen, that the conversion from tensorflow.js into Keras is possible, but did not found the conversion back.

Comment: Do you mean you want a model that you trained in Javascript to be converted to one that you can use in python?

Comment: Like to a format of "model.h5"?

Comment: yes exactly. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal enter the following command and just edit the path for the input model and where the output should be saved.

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tfjs_layers_model \
    --output_format=keras \
   my_layers_model/model.json
   my_keras_model/
```